# Quasiconcavity of $f(x) = \min\{k | \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| > 1\}$ with $f(x) = \infty$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n {|x_i| \leq 1}$

Tags: convex-analysis

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we define $f(x) = \min\{k | \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| > 1\}$ with $f(x) = \infty$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n {|x_i| \leq 1}$. How to use sublevel set to show the quasiconcavity of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show quasi concavity of $f$, we must show that the set 
$$C_{\alpha}=\{x:f(x)\geq\alpha\},$$
is convex for any $\alpha$. For this, we need to show that, if $y$ and $z$ are in $C_{\alpha}$, all convex combinations $\beta y+(1-\beta)z$ are in $C_{\alpha}$, where $\beta\in(0,1)$.

Pick any such $w=\beta y+(1-\beta)z$. Let $K$ be any integer smaller than $\alpha$. Then, by triangle inequality,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{K}|w_i|\leq\beta\sum_{i=1}^{K}|y_i|+(1-\beta)\sum_{i=1}^{K}|z_i|.$$
Since $y$ and $z$ are in $C_{\alpha}$, $\sum_{i=1}^{K}|y_i|\leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{K}|z_i|\leq 1$ (otherwise they cannot be members of $C_{\alpha}$). Hence,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{K}|w_i|\leq \beta*1+(1-\beta)*1\leq 1.$$
Hence, $f(w)\geq\alpha$, and hence $w\in C_{\alpha}$. Since $\beta$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question, it should be quasiconcavity.

Comment: Would it be more precise if the second equation is changed to $\leq$ (by triangle inequality) and it's $\sum_{i=1}^K |y_i| \leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^K |z_i| \leq 1$?

Comment: That's true. Incorporated.